# File ordering by screens parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, object

I have an array files[{screen:[1], order:1},{screen:[2], order: 2},{screen:[1, 2], order: 3}].

Each file can have screen - [1], [2], [1, 2], [2,3] and [1,2,3]

Depend on the screen each file have an order.

Example:

1. Add file1 with the screen [1] and order 1
2. Add file2 with the screen [2] and order 1
3. Add file3 with the screen [2] and order 2
4. Add file4 with the screen [1, 2] and order 3, why 3 - because on screen 1 we have order 1, on screen 2 we have 1 and 2, we get the max of first screen order and second screen order it's 2 and plus 1.
   But we can choose an order for file4 with screens [1, 2] from 1, 2 or 3
   If I choose 3 - it's ok
   If I choose 2 - file3 with the screen [2] and order need change the order to 3
   If I choose 1 - file1 need to change the order to 2, file2 order - 2, file3 order - 3.

It's ok with my code. 
But in this example I have problem

1. Add file1 with the screen [1, 2] and order 1
2. Add file2 with the screen [2] and order 2
3. Now, when I want to add file3 with the screen [1] and order 1 file1 change order to 2, but file2 which needs change order to 3 stays 2.

I try to do some loops in loops =) But I'm confused

```
let tempFiles = files; // all files Array of objects
      screen.forEach(s => { //screen - last added file's screen [1,2]
        tempFiles = tempFiles.map(file => {
          if(file.screen.indexOf(s) !== -1) {
            let order = file.order;
            if(file.order >= orderTemp) { //orderTemp - last added file's order
              file.screen.forEach(scr => {
                if(scr === s) {
                  order++;
                }
                else {
                  tempFiles.map(f => {
                    if(f.screen.indexOf(scr) !== -1){
                      let ord = f.order;
                      if(f.order >= order){
                        ord++;
                      }
                      return {...f, ord};
                    }
                    return f;
                  })
                } 
              })
            }
            return {...file, order}
          }
          return file;
        })
      })
```

Input:

```
files = [{screens:[1, 2], order: 1}, {screens: [2], order: 2}];
screen = [1];
orderTemp = 1;
```

Output:

```
files [{screens: [1, 2]}, order: 2, {screens: [2], order: 3}];
```

In the output of this code, I need to have all changed files with the right orders.

Comment: It might be better to show samples of input data, paired with expected output data, to make the question easier to follow

Comment: Thank you, I will add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I find a very good solution. I do it with recursion.
Here is my code:

```
const ordering = (screen, files, tempOrder) => {
    files.forEach((file, i) => {
      if (file.screen.indexOf(screen) !== -1) {
        let o = file.order;
        if (file.order === tempOrder) {
          o++;
          file.screen.forEach(scr => {
            ordering(scr, files, o)
          });
        }
        let arr = order[`order${screen}`];
        arr.push(o);
        setOrder({ ...order, [`order${screen}`]: [...arr] });
        files[i] = { ...file, order: o };
      }
    });
  };

screen.forEach(s => {
        ordering(s, tempFiles, orderTemp);
      });
```